# Basic Category Theory Question

Tags: category-theory

I'm working through Basic Category Theory by Leinster, and exercise $1.2.21$ states:

> Show that functors preserve isomorphism. That is, prove if $\mathscr{A} \rightarrow \mathscr{B}$ is a functor and $A,A' \in \mathscr{A}$ with $A \cong A'$, then $F(A) \cong F(A')$.

I know how to prove this; functors preserve function composition and identities, so for $f : A \rightarrow A'$ and $g: A' \rightarrow A$ where $fg = 1_{A'}$ and $gf = 1_A$, known to exist since $A \cong A'$, we have $F(f)F(g) = 1_{F(A')}$ and $F(g)F(f) = 1_{F(A)}$, hence $F(A) \cong F(A')$.

What I don't understand is why we are guaranteed that $F(f)$ and $F(g)$ exist. If the functor is full, then we are, but is there not a functor from every category to a discrete category?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In order to have well-defined functor, you need to specify the values of $F(f)$ and $F(g)$. This is similar to defining a function - you need to define it on a whole domain.

Comment: Thanks! Obvious in hindsight.